# Execute Talend job using Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, talend

I am trying to execute a Talend job using Airflow (using python scripting). Below are the steps I have followed:

1. After creating a Talend job, I did a BUILD and from the ZIP file created I took the ".sh" file.
2. Placed the .sh file in a S3 location.
3. did a "bash operator" import and tried to execute .sh file and I am getting "file not found" error.

**##code starts here##**

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

build_file_path = "s3://{}/talend-bash-file".format(S3_BUCKET)
file_path= "s3://aap_dl_intrepid_edw_mwaa_qa/mwaa/dags"
job_name = "job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing"
job_version = "0.1"

bash_command = file_path+"/"+job_name+"_"+job_version+"/"+job_name+"/"+job_name+"_run.sh"

with DAG
(
    dag_id=edw_dag_id,    
    start_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1, 00, 00), 
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    #template_searchpath = ["{}".format(template_searchpath)],
    on_success_callback=edw_common.send_dag_success_notification
) as dag:

    talend_airflow_connect = BashOperator(
        task_id = "talend_airflow_connect",
        #bash_command = 'sh job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing_0.1/job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing/job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing_run.sh --context_param file_path=/home/ec2-user/context/ --context_param file_name= TalendCredentials.txt',
        bash_command = bash_command,
        on_failure_callback = edw_common.send_failure_notification
    )
talend_airflow_connect >> final_status
```

**##code end here##**

```
error: bash_command: job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing_0.1/job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing/job_rdv_kafka_to_rdv_merch_hier_airflow_testing_run.sh - No such file or directory found
```

I have just pasted the bash_operator part here. Can anyone please help me here??

Comment: Did you try to pass the absolute path instead of the relative path of the talend shell script?

Comment: the shell script is placed inside S3 and I gave the full exact path also. But that didnt work out. -- @AlexandreJuma

Answer (score 0):

The way you mentioned I assume that you have uploaded the ".sh" file alone. Please make sure that you have uploaded the export of the whole Talend job as a folder. Not sure about the architecture you are following, in my case I have uploaded the Talend job export to the S3 bucket which was allocated for the Airflow DAGS, so that it will be accessible to the Airflow DAG. From there I was able to execute the Talend job using the following code in DAG

```
ingest_sample_data = BashOperator( task_id = 'ingest_sample_data', dag=dag, bash_command = 'cd /usr/local/airflow/dags/job_INGEST_sample_data_0.1/job_INGEST_sample_data/ && sh -x  job_INGEST_sample_data_run.sh ' )
```